# Etherape shows a huge number of nodes from my computer

Tags: networking, 16.04, etherape

My comp's internet was working really slowly on Ubuntu. It'd often start fast, and then slow down.

Then I'd not even be able to select or see which wifi network I'm connected to.

It'd be fine after a reboot for a while.

I installed EtherApe to track my network. I got an ever increasing number of new nodes by the name shaurya-linux-12345 (12345 > a number of different five digit).. have I found a problem, or are these just normal ports?

Please see the linked screenshot of the network.

[All these new nodes... what are these?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMB1K.png)

Comment: Run `sudo netstat -tulpn` to see which application is opening all those ports.

Comment: tcp 0 0 127.0.0.1:3306 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 10417/mysqld 
tcp 0 0 127.0.1.1:53 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 1924/dnsmasq 
tcp 0 0 127.0.0.1:631 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 7526/cupsd 
tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:17500 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 1734/dropbox 
tcp 0 0 127.0.0.1:17600 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 1734/dropbox 
tcp 0 0 127.0.0.1:17603 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 1734/dropbox 
tcp6 0 0 :::80 :::* LISTEN 10155/apache2 
tcp6 0 0 ::1:631 :::* LISTEN 7526/cupsd 
tcp6 0 0 :::17500 :::* LISTEN1734/dropbox 
udp 0 0 0.0.0.0:17500 0.0.0.0:*1734/dropbox 
udp 0 0 0.0.0.0:5353 0.0.0.0:*2114/vivaldi-bin
udp 0 0 0.0.0.0:5353 0.0.0.0:*808/avahi-daemon: r

Comment: udp 0 0 0.0.0.0:35747 0.0.0.0:* 1924/dnsmasq 
udp 0 0 0.0.0.0:60709 0.0.0.0:* 808/avahi-daemon: r
udp 0 0 127.0.1.1:53 0.0.0.0:* 1924/dnsmasq 
udp 0 0 0.0.0.0:68 0.0.0.0:* 6209/dhclient 
udp 0 0 0.0.0.0:631 0.0.0.0:* 857/cups-browsed
udp6 0 0 :::58197 :::* 808/avahi-daemon: r
udp6 0 0 :::5353 :::* 2114/vivaldi-bin
udp6 0 0 :::5353 :::* 808/avahi-daemon: r

Comment: Is this even readable? nothing seems weird to me though..
if you prefer, i can send you a readable screenshot

Comment: We don't need to see the output. It's for you. It's how you answer the question. Read it.

Comment: Run the command again without the '-l' flag to see more.