# How to detect someone's stealing CPU's resources or NAS's movies?

Tags: cpu, fan, lan

I noticed my NAS LAN LED's activity is always blinking, moreover today I used Windows and I realized that the fan noise was much much quieter than in Ubuntu. Of course this can be due to the fact I'm running many services in linux <paranoic_mode> but it can be somebody is stealing my resources. </paranoic_mode>?

This is a EtherApe screenshot.

[image: This is a EtherApe screenshot]

In particular do you know what is `unn-143-244-37-89-datapacket`? I saw a huge amount of data from my PC (lello) and that address.

Comment: https://www.abuseipdb.com/check/143.244.37.89 and https://www.ipqualityscore.com/free-ip-lookup-proxy-vpn-test/lookup/143.244.37.89

Comment: @ChanganAuto Thanks.
I got that almost one is malicious so now 1) how to get rid of it? 2) How to prevent that to happen again?

Comment: Without the VPN  the situation is even worse: [EtherApe screenshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TiukO5TW-NT-p_qRie8PZuHSJfAQ7QLd/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I started suspecting that the NAS' LAN LED fast blinking is due to high traffic volume in the LAN. I found a [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/917825/etherape-shows-a-huge-number-of-nodes-from-my-computer) that is almost the same but, sadly, hasn't any solution.

Comment: That second etherape screenshot is full of ICMP pings, so either your router is configured to allow direct ICMP to that machine or it is doing some scanning.

Comment: I just checked: my router doesn't mention "ICMP". How can I block all of that non wanted traffic?